# Should I seal these openings in the siding that were cut for the electrical wire?

Tags: siding, vinyl-siding

We had our siding replaced and I noticed that where they cut it for the electrical, cable, and car charger that it's not sealed but I feel like it should be or water is just going to run down and get behind the siding. Should I caulk this or put something else here or is this okay?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The bottom picture can be sealed with caulking.  Quite sure the top picture needs more work, those cables should be protected from touching/rubbing against the siding(metal or aluminum siding would be dangerous like that).  Might need conduit/tubing added there.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, they did a lousy job where your CATV goes into your house. You should seal that with some grey silicone caulk. You might want to put those cables in grey conduit to clean up the area. Also run a bead of caulk around the conduit for your charger and also on the seam above the conduit.

Comment: Call the installer back and tell them to finish the job!  This isn't something that a homeowner should have to do; sealing in a professional manner is part of the job of the siding installer.